# zsh prompt function not running

Tags: zsh

I am trying to learn about custom prompts in zsh, and I am having the following issue:

With this code:

```
print_dir(){
  echo $PWD 
}

export PROMPT=$'%{%F{134}%}$(print_dir)%{%f%}
%{%F{231}%}❯%{%f%} '
```

I get this output instead of the result of the function:

```
$(project_pwd)
```

I know this function is not needed here, but I want to expand it as I learn.

Why is the function not executing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do `setopt prompt_subst`.  This is documented in the `zshoptions` man page, which viewable on the [zsh website](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#Prompting).

Comment: dude, awesome.  thanks a bunch.  I was referring to peoples dotfiles, but wasnt focused on config.zsh